# Lambda Expression object mapping issue

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have *PrimaryDTO* class which contains a `List<SecondaryDTO>` and this *SecondaryDTO* itself contains a `Set<SecondaryCategoryDTO>` and finally this *SecondaryCategoryDTO* contains a boolean *status*.

In the below statement, I want to check if any *status* is **true** then go inside if statement else don't enter.

```
if(Optional.ofNullable(PrimaryDTO.getSecondaryDTOs()).
    orElse(PrimaryDTO.getSecondaryDTOs()).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(x->x.getSecondaryCategories()).anyMatch(z-> z.isStatus()==true))
```

But, in the above syntax, *z.isStatus()* is giving error as it is saying z to be a *set*. I am already iterating Set via *.map* with *getSecondaryCategories()*. I am not getting why it is taking it as set?

Comment: What’s the purpose of `Optional.ofNullable(PrimaryDTO.getSecondaryDTOs()). orElse(PrimaryDTO.getSecondaryDTOs())`? Doesn’t it always evaluate to `PrimaryDTO.getSecondaryDTOs()`, no matter whether it is `null`? Besides that, you are not iterating the `Set`, you are just mapping to it. Perhaps, you meant `.flatMap(x -> x.getSecondaryCategories().stream())`…

Comment: Thanks @Holger for the comment on Optional, Its a mistake. I didn't got on how to execute the statement if not null since if I use ifPresent, then I cannot throw any Exception from inside it. It asks for try catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might have `PrimaryDTO` as a null *and* it's `List<SecondaryDTO>` as a null, *and* some elements in that `List` might be null also, in such a case:

```
Optional<Boolean> op = Optional.ofNullable(primaryDTO)
            .flatMap(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x.getSecondaryDTOs()))
            .map(x -> x.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .flatMap(y -> y.getSecondaryCategoryDTOs().stream())
                    .map(SecondaryCategoryDTO::isStatus)
                    .anyMatch(z -> z == true)); 

if(op.isPresent()){
    // do your work
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene and Holger for the solution. Its working now. I tried with flatmap but in an incorrect way.

Comment: @harshit if you want everything inside the if condition `if(Optional.ofNullable(primaryDTO)
                .flatMap(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x.getSecondaryDTOs()))
                .filter(x -> x.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .flatMap(y -> y.getSecondaryCategories().stream())
                        .anyMatch(SecondaryCategoryDTO::isStatus)).isPresent()){...};`

Comment: `.map(SecondaryCategoryDTO::isStatus)
                    .anyMatch(z -> z == true)` could be simplified to `.anyMatch(SecondaryCategoryDTO::isStatus)`

Comment: @Aomine this is how I wanted to do initially, but since the OP seems to be confused about `Optional` in general, i wanted to be as verbose as I could here...

Comment: Thanks @Aomine for the alternative solution. It is much helpful. Eugene, Thanks for the simplified solution as it was easy to understand the thing.

Comment: `.flatMap(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x.getSecondaryDTOs()))` is a verbose variant of `.map(x -> x.getSecondaryDTOs())`… Besides that, it’s still confusing. Is the whole operation truly about whether the optional is *present* or is it about containing `true`? Here, the `Opional` is only absent/empty, when either, `primaryDTO` is `null` or `getSecondaryDTOs()` returned `null`. Otherwise, it’s present, but may contain `false`.